# Solving the equation X^4 - DY^4 = Z^4

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Let's have the equations $12^4 - DY^4 = 7^4$ and $24^4 - DY^4 = 19^4$. For what values of *D* and *Y* do these equations have a solution?

Secondly, what little trick is required to obtain solutions of the equation
$X^4 - DY^4 = Z^4$ where *X, D, Y, Z* are positive integers with a GCD of 1?

HINT: Let's have the quantity $4f^3 + 6f^2 + 4f + 1$. If we set $f = (k - 1 / 2)$ then we obtain the cubic equation $4k^3 + k$. Let's set $4k^3 + k = m$ where *m* a positive integer. If this equation gives a rational solution, eg. *d/p*, then from there on you have to figure out how to solve the equation $X^4 - DY^4 = Z^4$.

2nd HINT: $24^4- 322.328 * 5^4 = 19^4$

<sub>The equations, in order of appearance: 12^4 - D * (Y^4) = 7^4, then 24^4 - D * (Y^4) = 19^4, then X^4 - D * (Y^4) = Z^4</sub>
<sub>Equations from the hint, in order of appearance: 4f^3 + 6f^2 + 4f + 1, then f = (k - 1 / 2), then 4k^3 + k, then 4k^3 + k = m, then X^4 - D * (Y^4) = Z^4</sub>
<sub>Equation from the second hint: 24^4 - 322.328 * 5^4 = 19^4</sub>

Comment: $12^4 - 7^4 = 18335$, which is the product of the primes 5, 19 and 193. Therefore, $D = 18335$ and $Y = 1$. $24^4 - 19^4 = 201455$, that leads to a contradiction?!

Comment: Could you clarify (1) whether "... have a GCD of 1" means that there isn't a nontrivial factor of _all_ of them, or that they're _pairwise_ coprime, and (2) whether you're asking for ways to find _all_ (x,y,z,d) satisfying the condition, or _some_ (x,y,z,d), or something else, e.g. some (x,y,z) given d for which any exist?

Comment: @ Glorfindel. your ansewrs are incorect you have to try harder to find the values of  D,Y.

Comment: @Gareth. (1) X,D,Y,Z do not have a common factor. The first two equations do not have integer value for  D.The conditions for the second part of the question are very clear and do not need any further explanation. (2) It takes a different way of thinking to solve the second part of the question. I will add HINT.

Comment: I don't get how D does not have an integer value, yet X, D, Y, Z are positive integers.

Comment: @ Weather As  i said above the first two equations  have a different way of solvability. because D  is a desimal ..

Comment: Plainly from the first 2 equations $DY^4 = 18335$ but $DY^4 = 201455$ so @Glorfindel 's contradiction stands. The second question uses a $D$ with different conditions from the first question. Are the $D$ and $Y$ in the first question different from *each other* – are there two *sets* of $D,Y$? So is question 1 itself in two parts?

Comment: Unless I'm seriously misunderstanding the question, all parts can be trivially solved by setting $Y=1$.

Comment: I cannot understand the negative votes. The material presented here is original mathematics.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis I think the sentence "For what values of D and Y do these equations have a solution?" is the main source of confusion/frustration (and therefore downvotes). In order to discuss a *solution* to an *equation*, it should have one or more unknowns. But "For what values of D and Y" means the two are given constants, so we have no unknowns to solve the equation for. Maybe you wanted to ask "For what values of Y do these equations have a solution for D?" or just "For what values of D and Y are the equations satisfied?"

Comment: @VassilisParassidis That said, I have more questions. In part 1, are D and Y integers only? In part 2, I think you didn't clarify "X, D, Y, Z have a GCD of 1". Which of these do you mean exactly: GCD(X,D,Y,Z) = 1 or GCD(X,D) = GCD(X,Y) = GCD(X,Z) = GCD(D,Y) = GCD(D,Z) = GCD(Y,Z) = 1?

Comment: Also in part 2, do you want *all* solutions of (X,D,Y,Z) to the equation, or is generating just some (but infinitely many) of them OK?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a mathematics puzzle or question? Thank you.

Comment: Wow this is like the most minused puzzle I've ever seen. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you found an interesting relationship between the quartic equation $x^4-dy^4=z^4$ and the cubic polynomial $4f^3+6f^2+4f+1$ by yourself, which is good for you. But such finding doesn't warrant a good puzzle, especially in the form of such a broad question (since it is *very* likely that there are multiple ways to approach the problem, some of which may be much simpler than you thought).

For this problem, all *three* parts (counting the two equations in Q1 as two separate parts) can be solved with basic number theory.

#### Part 1a/1b

As Glorfindel calculated already, the equations to solve are $dy^4 = 18335$ and $dy^4 = 201455$ respectively. Both numbers are the product of three distinct primes, namely $18335 = 5 \times 19 \times 193$ and $201455 = 5 \times 43 \times 937$.

If $d$ and $y$ are limited to integers,

> they have only one solution each, since neither is divisible by any prime fourth power. Therefore the only solutions are $d=18335, y=1$ and $d=201455, y=1$ respectively.

If they can be anything broader than that, there are infinitely many solutions:

> Consider the first equation $dy^4 = 18335$. For any value of $y \ne 0$, $d$ can have the value of $18335\over y^4$. This holds for rationals (for any rational $y$, $d$ is also rational), and for reals (ditto). Even if we limit them to finite decimals, we can pick any $y=2^n 5^m$ where $n,m$ are integers (can be positive, 0, or negative).

#### Part 2

If you mean by "GCD is 1" that $GCD(d,x,y,z) = 1$,

> just plug in $y=1$ and choose any integers for $x$ and $z$. Then evaluate the value of $d=x^4-z^4$. Then the GCD condition is trivially satisfied (since GCD of 1 and any other integer is 1).

If you mean that the numbers are *pairwise* coprime, i.e. $GCD(d,x) = GCD(d,y) = \cdots = GCD(y,z) = 1$,

> pick two coprime positive integers $x$ and $z$, so that $x > z$. Then we get $dy^4 = x^4 - z^4$. Since $GCD(x,z) = 1$, it follows that $GCD(x^4, z^4) = GCD(x^4, x^4-z^4) = GCD(z^4, x^4-z^4) = 1$. This means that, if $d$ and $y$ are coprime, all four numbers are pairwise coprime. One trivial way to pick $d$ and $y$ is $d=x^4-z^4$ and $y=1$. For a non-trivial solution, check if the prime factorization of $x^4-z^4$ contains a term $p^{4k}$ (i.e. the number should be divisible by $p$ *exactly* $4k$ times). If such term exists, we can find another solution: $y=p^k, d=(x^4-z^4)\div p^{4k}$ satisfying $GCD(d,y) = 1$.

It is even possible to generate infinitely many non-trivial solutions ($y>1$):

> Pick any odd prime $p$. Choose $x$ and $z$ so that $x+z=p^4$ and $GCD(x,p) = GCD(z,p) = 1$. Then $GCD(x+z,x-z) = 1$ and $GCD(x^2+z^2, x^2-z^2)=1$, so we have $p^4$ in the prime factorization of $x^4-z^4$. Then let $y=p$ and $d=(x^4-z^4)\div y^4$.
>
> Demonstration: Let $p=3$, and choose $x=41, z=40$ so that $x+z = 81 = 3^4$. Then $x^4-z^4 = 41^4-40^4 = 265761 = 3^4 \times 17 \times 193$, exactly as predicted. So we can pick $y=3, d=17\times 193 = 3281$, and the resulting equation is $41^4 - 3281 \times 3^4 = 40^4$, and you can easily see that the four numbers are pairwise coprime.
>
> This construction also works if we choose $x-z=p^4$ instead or we choose *any odd number* $p>1$, as long as $GCD(x,p) = GCD(z,p) = 1$.

---

For the first hint, if $4k^3 + k = m$ with $m$ an integer has a rational solution for $k$, it is necessarily an integer $n$ or a half-integer $\frac{n}2$. I don't get how $m=15, k=\frac32$ gives rise to the equation $5^4 - 34 \times 2^4 = 3^4$ (which was mentioned in OP's comment), but $m=34, k=2$ surely does:

$$(f+1)^4 - f^4 = 34 \\ (k+\frac12)^4 - (k-\frac12)^4 = 34 \\ \left( \frac52 \right)^4 - \left( \frac32 \right)^4 = 34 \\ 5^4 - 3^4 = 34 \times 2^4 \\ 5^4 - 34 \times 2^4 = 3^4
$$

For $m=15, k=\frac32$, I get this:

$$(k+\frac12)^4 - (k-\frac12)^4 = 15 \\ 2^4 - 1^4 = 15 \\ 2^4 - 15 \times 1^4 = 1^4
$$

...which is a "trivial" solution, as $y=1$.

Also, my last part of Part 2 solution can be extended to include these as well (as the GCD condition seems to be $GCD(d,x,y,z)=1$):

> Allow $p$ to be even numbers too, and keep the $GCD(x,z) = 1$ constraint. By picking $p=2$ and using $x-z=p$, all solutions intended by OP can be generated in this way.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Your hint 2 is just *one* correct answer. I can give you many others: $1145.9375 \times 2^4$, $1.8335 \times 10^4$, $0.0469376 \times 25^4$, and so on. If you're rejecting my solution for some reason, you need to include that reason as a condition in the original question.

Comment: I made a mistake, Instead of $4k^3 +4k=m$ it should read $4k^3+k=m$. If $m=15$ then one root of this equation is $3/2$ from which we formulate the equation $5^4-34*2^4=3^4$. The answer to the first part of my question is $12^4 - 29.336 * 5^4 = 7^4$. I specified  that $D$ is a decimal number. The other solution is contained in HINT 2.The value of $D$ is obtained with a special formula.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Can you explain why $1145.9375 \times 2^4$ is rejected? Because 1145.9375 is a decimal number just like 322.328 or 29.336.

Comment: In the equations I gave, only $D$ is allowed to be a decimal.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis D = 1145.9375 is a decimal and Y = 2 is an integer. (Also you didn't say that in the question.)

Comment: @VassilisParassidis The worst part of the "puzzle" is that guessing a special formula when there is a more general one (or guessing one when there are multiple equivalent ways to get the same results) is not fun.

Comment: There is another mistake too, in the footnote. f = (k - 1) / 2 was edited in the main text but not in the footnote.

Comment: @  Bubbler. You can go to MathOverflow find my name click on Vassilis Parassidis and  you will find there an extended discussion of the given equation.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the footnote is something I added to help with accessibility (since MathJax can be hard for screen readers). I haven't noticed this post being edited since. I just updated the footnote.

Comment: @bobble OP edited the MathJax part in revision 5. I only noticed later that the footnote had not been edited to keep step, but didn't realise it was your footnote.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis I read your post on MathOverflow. It's interesting, but it doesn't give the most general solution to your equation. It's like saying "I solved Pythagorean triplets problem $x^2+y^2=z^2$ with $x = 2n+1, y=2n^2+2n, z=2n^2+2n+1$" when it cannot give triplets like 8, 15, 17. Can you generate $41^4-3281\times 3^4=40^4$ with your formula?