# Equation $X^4-DY^4=Z^4$ (Part 1)

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Let's have the positive integers X,Y,Z. The number D is a terminating decimal always. The numbers X,Y,Z do not have a common factor. Based on the above information, can you solve the following equations?

$41^4-DY^4=33^4$

$X^4-419.992*5^4=Z^4$

The solution to the equation 41^4-DY^4=33^4 is  41^4-400.35156258*8^4=33^4
next time i will put easier questions.

Comment: May I suggest that you remove everything up to and including "On part one", so the question begins with "X,Y,.."? Those parts add nothing but clutter to the question.

Comment: @Bass. Thanks for the suggestion. I removed that part.

Comment: For those without context: this is a repost of [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105026/71652).

Comment: @Bubbler.. Bass suggested that I remove the context, so I did.

Comment: The comments are a much better place to mention the context, it doesn't get in the way of the actual question there.

Comment: Based on my answer to your last question, I maintain that your "special" formula is not *special* but just *arbitrary*, and, while the equation is an interesting subject of mathematics, you should not post this as a *puzzle* as the fully general solution is yet unknown. Also, this is a dupe of your last question under SE rules.

Comment: Please stop insisting your "intended answer" which is mathematically WRONG, or underspecified at least. The information in the post is not sufficient to lead to your conclusion. If you're hiding the "special formula" because it will spoil the puzzle, it is not a good puzzle in the first place since the **correct answer** to the problem as written is now Bass's, not yours.

Comment: There is now a [meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7070) about this puzzle and its predecessor.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis, it's been explained to you that there are multiple solutions to this equation. It's not that this question is "hard", and therefore you need to post "easier questions" - it's that your "correct answer"/"solution" ***is not unique***.

Answer (score 1):

Trying all the fourth powers (such that the difference between two consecutive ones is smaller than the numeric value in the second equation), we get that

> $X=26$ and $Z=21$.

This is enough to show us that

> No, we cannot figure out Y

because

> 5 isn't a factor of either X or Z, so if there's some (D,Y) pair that's a solution, then $$(\frac{1}{5^4}D, 5Y)$$ is also a solution:
>
>  If D is a terminating decimal, so is $\frac{1}{5^4}D = .00000256 \times D$.
>  Obviously, if Y is an integer, so is 5Y, and if Y didn't share any factors with 21 and 26, then neither will 5Y.

Comment: The solution is $(26^4-21^4)/625=419.992$.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis I have absolutely no idea what you mean by that comment. The solution to what is 419.992? X and Z are clearly solved above, and Y is clearly proved unsolvable.

Comment: @Bass.X=26,  Y=5,  Z=21,   D=419.992  this equation is clearly solvable as stated in  my comment.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis If you bother to actually read the answer you'll find that if Y=5 is a possible solution, then Y=25 also possible, so it's impossible to solve for Y. (Except in terms of D). Just as importantly, did you ever try plugging those numbers into the equations? And I mean, like, *really actually* calculating the value of $41^4-419.992\times5^4 = 2563266$ and comparing it with $33^4=1185921$?

Comment: The value of D is obtained from a formula when X,Z, are fixed then D has only one value.,419.992*625=262495 ,  26^4=456976,  21^4=194481 so 456976-262495=194481.

Comment: The second equation has different values for D and Y you will find that when you solve the other equation 41^4-DY^4=33^4.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis It really cannot follow your train of thought. Maybe you are suggesting that I need to solve for some constant values that are already given in the question? Maybe you are suggesting D and Y somehow appear in the same equation with X or Z? (They don't.) Maybe you are just trying to restate in so many more words what is written in the first spoiler block of the answer? Maybe something else completely? Who knows! Whichever the case, I'm afraid I won't be reading any further comments here.

Comment: There are three equations, one in the title and two in the body of the question. The three equations are obviously incompatible, as $41^4 - 33^4$ is not equal to $419.992 \times 5^4$. @VassilisParassidis I think this shows that your question has at least some issue, which you should improve. My guess is that one or more letters are used for different meanings, which is certainly confusing. This answer simply ignores the equation in the title and sticks to what is written in the body.

Comment: @ Whatsup .The equation x^2-DY^2=1 has different solutions  for each value of D.The same applies here the only differences is the solutions in the above equation are more complicated.On the title we have the general expression of the equation on the other two  the value of  D is specific.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis You failed to convey that in the question. If that is the purpose, you should have given just D and leave X, Y, and Z as unknowns. *That* is a much more interesting, nontrivial puzzle. (Using a non-integer value of D is still a total nonsense here.)

Comment: @VassilisParassidis But still I have to reiterate that your "general solution" is not universal: for example, your formula fails to find a solution for D=3281, as [the roots to your cubic are not rational](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+abs%284x%5E3%2Bx%29%3D3281). So it works only with a specific class of D. If you're planning to ask a general version of the question again, you should describe that specific class of D; otherwise it doesn't work as a puzzle.